# How to remove buttons from slider/carosuel in splidejs

Tags: splidejs

I've created a slider with turned on autoplay, so I've figured out that I have to get rid of those buttons. But I don't know

I haven't find this kind of an option while reading documentation for splidejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to set  arrows to false like this

```
var primarySlider = new Splide( '#primary-slider', {
    arrows     : false // disbale arrows
} );
```